# Cannot send message from console to discord

Tags: python, console, discord, discord.py, message

So I'm trying to send a message from the console to discord as if it were a `/say` command. Specifically I'm trying to input the channel id and a message, and get the bot to send it.

But when I run it no error appears, the bot goes online, and nothing is sent to the text channel

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


TOKEN = open('token.txt').readline()
client = discord.Client()
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot


channel_entry = input('ID: ')
msg_entry = input('Mensagem: ')

@client.event
async def send_channel_entry():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_entry)
    await channel.send(msg_entry)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Could you please describe what your problem is in more details, your question is quite hard to understand. Some debugging info might help as well, how do you know that the message is not sent?

Comment: sry my English is bad

Comment: i'm trying to send a message through the console
as if it were a / say command
I'm trying to specify the channel id and the message I want and make the bot send it

I know I didn't send it because I'm looking at the text channel and nothing comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course nothing happens, because `send_channel_entry` is never called. Have you tried calling the command or activating it via Discord to see if it works?